# Get Likes on fb fan page but referrals to website

Tags: facebook

Ideally this is what I would want:

- I have a fb fan page with around 2000 likes. I also have a fb app by
  which I can run social plugins on my website. I put up a like button
  using the following code on my website: `{fb:like
  href="http://facebook.com/traveltriangle"}`
- I want to show Like button on my website such that if user clicks on
  it, my fan page's 'like' increases. However I also want that for the
  post that goes on user's timeline, it links to my website and not to my fan page.

How do I achieve this?

I am also fine if I change `href` in the `fb:like` code to point it to my website. However then the referral links are good, but I can not use those likes to post my users later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use merge tam. Fb Fan page is one thing and Fb App is other thing. FB App helps you get user data from what I know from their database while Fan page helps you promote your business. 
Why do you need to merge them?

Comment: Sorry for the earlier post. I have defined my objective clearly now